# Nativescript Stuck at Copying template files

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line-interface, nativescript

I have a NativeScript + angular project it was working fine until i upgraded my cli to 7.0.3
now i can't run the following :

```
tns run android --bundle
```

because it get stuck at :

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Copying template files...
```

I've tried to wait more than an hour all it created was `platform` folder with `android` and `temp-android` and not the complete project it use to generate

my environment is currently like this when i run `ng --version` from cmd i get :

```
Angular CLI: 6.1.0-beta.0
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.7.0-beta.0
@angular-devkit/core         0.7.0-beta.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.0-beta.0
@schematics/angular          0.7.0-beta.0
@schematics/update           0.7.0-beta.0
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   2.7.2
```

when i run the same command from powershell i get this :

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.3
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.3
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.3
@angular/cli                      7.0.3
@angular/language-service         7.0.1
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.3
@schematics/angular               7.0.3
@schematics/update                0.10.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.19.1
```

every thing got missed up , i need a way to fix the current or rollback to the previous status .

from my search i thing the problem is related to npm , is there a way to clear cash or remove the the package and reinstall them with right versions .

**UPDATE**

after leaving the command for 2 hours i got this error

```
Unable to apply changes on device: CB5A28949S. Error is: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/tns-android failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:59069.
Executing after-watch hook from D:\IdeaProjects\AndroidAppsLauncher\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch
Executing after-watch hook from D:\IdeaProjects\AndroidAppsLauncher\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
```

Noting that i'm not using a proxy

**UPDATE**

regarding last update , apperenlty tns had a proxy i removed it `tns proxy clear`
but the copying files issue still exists

**UPDATE**

It worked !!! , I changed nothing , I only kept creating new projects and trying to run then suddenly it build and copied the files in 2 secs !
I feel like it was trying to connecting to back end interface that was down for that time which i think is really inconvenient, there should be an offline mode.